# Browse definition in Coq-IDE

Tags: coq, coqide, proof-general

In the Isabelle proof assistant, one can click Ctrl+click on a term and the IDE redirects him to the relevant definition.

Can this be done with CoqIde? With Proof-General?

Comment: somewhat related, in Isabelle I can also see a definition using the thm command. by writing thm mydef_def. would this be possible in Coq?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the features you mention in your post and in your comment (as an aside, feel free to edit your question to incorporate your comment) are possible in [Proof-General](https://proofgeneral.github.io/) and/or [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq#readme) (an Emacs package gathering IDE extensions of Proof-General):

- to see the content of a definition `def` (equivalent of [`Print def.`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=about#coq:cmd.print)): <kbd>C-c C-a C-p def RET</kbd>
- to see the type of a definition `def` (equivalent of [`Check def.`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=about#coq:cmd.check)): <kbd>C-c C-a C-c def RET</kbd>
- to see the type and related metadata of a definition `def` (equivalent of [`About def.`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=about#coq:cmd.about)): <kbd>C-c C-a C-b def RET</kbd>
- to see all this in one go for the identifier under point (requires **company-coq**): <kbd>C-c C-d</kbd>
- to be redirected to the location of the definition under point (requires **company-coq**): <kbd>M-.</kbd>
- to make the definition under point show up without moving (requires **company-coq**): <kbd><C-down-mouse-1></kbd>

#### Reminders

Just to be self-contained, the Emacs keybindings <kbd>C-c</kbd>, <kbd>M-.</kbd>, <kbd>RET</kbd>, <kbd><C-down-mouse-1></kbd> refer to <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+.</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> (without releasing the mouse button).

Finally you can discover the list of bindings associated to the ambient mode by doing <kbd>C-h m</kbd>:

<kbd>C-h k</kbd> `[describe-key]` <kbd>C-h m</kbd> `[describe-mode]`:

```
C-h m runs the command describe-mode (found in global-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘help.el’.

It is bound to C-h m, <f1> m, <help> m, <menu-bar> <help-menu>
<describe> <describe-mode>.

(describe-mode &optional BUFFER)

Display documentation of current major mode and minor modes.
A brief summary of the minor modes comes first, followed by the
major mode description.  This is followed by detailed
descriptions of the minor modes, each on a separate page.

[…]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, do you know about Coq IDE?

Comment: Regarding the 6 items I mentioned in my answer, I know that the first three are directly available in CoqIde through the [Query pane feature](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/practical-tools/coqide.html?highlight=coqide#queries), but I'm unsure for the other items.